# Can I use `abstract` keyword in C++ class

Tags: c++, keyword

Can we write abstract keyword in C++ class?

Comment: Sure, we can do it. Unfortunately the code will not compile, though =)

Comment: What about the abstract keyword in Visual C++ (Micrsoft specific). Its not standard, or well implemented in my opinion, but it counts, doesn't it? :P

Comment: In addition to pure virtual functions in C++ I do mark abstract classes with an "A_" as Class name prefix in any language e.g. "A_MyAbstractClass". I personally find this quite useful.

Answer (score 56):

No.

Pure virtual functions, in C++, are declared as:

```
class X
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Any class having at least one of them is considered abstract.

Comment: Missing return type. Also the method should be virtual.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you. Man, I have to get my head out of code maintenance and into writing new code once in a while - it dissolves your brain only looking at other people's errors. :-D

Answer (score 9):

It is a keyword introduced as part of the C++/CLI language spefication for the .NET framework.

Comment: Technically, it's a Microsoft C++ extension for native code even if you don't target .NET, so it's not C++/CLI specific. Just an extension, same as `__interface` or `__declspec(property)`. Still not ISO C++ of course.

Comment: No downvotes but C++ implies standard C++. Any XYZ non-standard implementation has to be explicitly specified and until such a specification has been made there is no reason to acknowledge its existence.

Answer (score 5):

As others point out, if you add a pure virtual function, the class becomes abstract.

However, if you want to implement an abstract base class with no pure virtual members, I find it useful to make the constructor protected. This way, you force the user to subclass the ABC to use it.

Example:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base()
    {
    }

public:
    void foo()
    {
    }

    void bar()
    {
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child()
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

actually keyword `abstract` exists in C++ (VS2010 at least) and I found it can be used to declare a class/struct as non-instantiated.

```
struct X abstract {
    static int a;
    static void foX(){};
};
int X::a = 0;
struct Y abstract : X { // something static
};
struct Z : X { // regular class
};
int main() {
    X::foX();
    Z Zobj;
    X Xobj;    // error C3622
}
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0z6b513%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `abstract` is not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Non standard but since it's a non-functional sanity check it's easily fixed with a conditional `#define` on other compilers as per Ken's answer.

Comment: @cz What does `#define abstract` achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Most C++ compilers do not have an `abstract` keyword.

### A Cheap Abstract Keyword

Although you could define a macro with that name like so:

```
#define abstract

class foo abstract { ... };
```

It would have absolutely no effect on the class, however, if any variable, function, anything is named "abstract", that `#define` is not going to make your code happy.

### Create an Abstract Class

As mentioned by others, you can force a class to be abstract by creating a Pure Virtual function and set it to `0` like so:

```
class foo
{
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

foo::func() { /* some default code [not required] */ }
```

**Pro:** Since even a pure virtual function can have a body, you can make a class abstract even though the very function you defined as abstract (pure virtual) is defined. However, contrary to the other virtual functions, having a body is not required of pure virtual functions.

**Con:** You are forced to create at least one pure virtual function and that forces all derived classes to define that function to not be viewed as abstract. If you anyway have such a function, then great! But often, this is not the case.

### The Correct Way

There is actually an astute way of creating an abstract class which is not well known. You still have to create a pure virtual function... and the fact is that the destructor can be a pure virtual function! There is ALWAYS a destructor in a class that uses the `virtual` keyword, so there is no hesitation here.

```
class foo {
    virtual ~foo() = 0;
};

foo * f(new foo);   // this fails, foo is abstract
```

The classes that derive from foo must now declare an explicit destructor (newer compilers properly create one implicitly, but it would still be a pure virtual function) which is not pure virtual like so:

```
class bar : public foo {
    virtual ~bar() override {}
};
```

Note that we do not have an `abstract` keyword, but we do have an `override` keyword, which is super useful so when a function signature changes, you cannot compile until all the classes that derive from your base class have their virtual functions updated accordingly.

#### Effect of the Default Destructor

An interesting aspect to using the destructor as the pure virtual function is that derived classes automatically get a destructor (if you don't define one) and means your derived classes are automatically non-abstract (assuming only the destructor is a pure virtual in the base class).

In other words, you could declare `bar` with:

```
class bar : public foo {
    void some_function();
};
```

and it automatically is not abstract because the default destructor is not abstract as it will more or less look like this:

```
    virtual ~bar() override {}
```

if you don't define it yourself.

In other words, if you want to define another layer which still is abstract (i.e. if you want `new bar` to fail to compile), then you must declare your own destructor and mark it as a pure virtual:

```
class bar : public foo {
    virtual ~bar() override = 0;
    void some_function();
};

bar::~bar() {}
```

(the `{}` and `= 0` can't be used together so you have to declare the destructor body separately.)