# Abstract base member variable in base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to specify an interface which requires an abstract class to have a certain type as a member variable.

I'll try to replicate the situation here:

```
class Blob {
  int data[32];
};
class Worker {
  string name;
  abstract void workOn(Blob&) = 0;
}

class Abstract {
  vector<shared_ptr<W>> workerList;
  Blob allTheStuff;
  abstract void somethingElse() = 0;
  void doAllTheWork() {
    for (w : workerList) {
      w->workOn(allTheStuff);
    }
  }
};

class B_Blob : public Blob {
  int moreData[4096];
};

class BulbasaurTrainingCamp : public Abstract {
  B_Blob allTheStuff;
  void somethingElse() {} // implemented
  // this class will accept Bulbasaurs into workerList
};

class Bulbasaur : Worker {
  Bulbasaur(): name("Fushigidane") {}
  void workOn(Blob& b) {
    // bulbasaurs cover *all* their workspace with crap
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(b.data[0])/sizeof(b.data); ++i) {
      b.data[i] = *((int*)&("crap"));
    }
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(b.moreData[0])/sizeof(b.moreData); ++i) {
      b.moreData[i] = *((int*)&("crap"));
    }
}
```

Here, the abstract bas class has a `Blob`, but the instance of `BulbasaurTrainingCamp` has a derived `B_Blob`. It appears that since I gave it the same name, the compiler accepts it.

Is there a name for this? What I want to know is what the behavior is when I do this. Have I overridden the `Blob` with the `B_Blob`?

I am basically not sure about whether there is an inaccessible base `Blob` instance hanging around inside of `BulbasaurTrainingCamp`. My expectation is that each `Bulbasaur` will write 16512 (not 16384) bytes of `crap` across the two member variables of `B_Blob`. I am hoping that C++ will actually do what appears to be the sensible thing. It's a case of, "it compiles so I think I should be happy, but I'm still not totally sure it's doing what I think it should be doing".

Comment: I wasn't aware that `abstract` can be used in C++ code.

Comment: I dunno. Maybe it can be left out? I've always put it in there to signal that a class may end up being non-instantiable

Comment: @DietmarKühl news to me too "It is a keyword introduced as part of the C++/CLI language spefication for the .NET framework." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298093/can-i-use-abstract-keyword-in-c-class

Comment: Basically @StevenLu, its not, strictly speaking, legal C++

Comment: There are more constructs which certainly don't work in C++, e.g. `for (w : workerList)`.

Comment: it should be `for(auto w : workerList)`, it's valid c++11

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class base
    {
    public: 
        int sameName;
        base(int x):sameName(x){}
    };
    class derived : public base
    {
    public:
        int diffName;
        int sameName;
        derived(int x,int i,int j):base(x),diffName(i),sameName(j){}

    };
    derived example(1,2,3);
    cout<<example.sameName<<endl;
    cout<<example.diffName<<endl;
    cout<<example.base::sameName<<endl;
}
```

The result is 3 2 1. 
I hope the example could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A base class, even an abstract one, will be included in its entirety within any derived classes. The new `allTheStuff` name hides the old one, but does not suppress its inclusion; the base class version can still be accessed using `Abstract::allTheStuff`. Worse, the function `doAllTheWork` will end up accessing the base class `allTheStuff` because it can't possibly know there's an identically-named member variable in a subclass.

If you want this kind of behaviour, you have a few decent options:

1. Don't put any meaningful code or data in the base class; leave it as a pure interface. This may result in code duplication (but you may be able to factor it out into new base classes or shared helper functions).
2. Use a dynamically sizable container type as the `Blob`, so you can dynamically ask for more or less space in the constructor.
3. Make `Blob` a separate inheritance hierarchy (e.g. `B_Blob` and `S_Blob` inherit from an abstract `Blob` with differing amounts of space allocated), with a virtual function in `Abstract` that returns the `Blob` to use.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be somehow assuming that this code compiles using C++. It certainly doesn't. Even after patching about various of the C++/CLI specifics, it remains that a `Blob` does not have a data member called `moreData` and the only way to get at it (using C++) is to use a suitable cast.

The `BulbasaurTrainingCamp` objects will have two members called `allTheStuff`, one of type `Blob` and one of type `B_Blob`. Which one you get depends on which type you are looking at (since all members are private, you won't get any, but let's ignore that detail) and/or which qualification you use:

```
BulbasaurTrainignCamp btc;
B_Blob&               b_blob = bts.allTheStuff;
Blob&                 blob1  = bts.Abstract::allTheStuff;

Abstract& abstract;
Blob&     blob2 = abstract.allTheStuff;
```

That is, when using something which looks like a `BulbasaurTrainingCamp` you can access both the `Blob` and the `B_Blob` objects but you need to use qualification to access `Abstract`s `allTheStuff` member. When using an `Abstract` you can only access `Abstract`s `Blob` object.